# Making a div flash just once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my div flash or highlight just once on a particular click event. I tried the following code

```
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('divId');
   setInterval(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 500);
}
```

But I keeps blinking. I want to use just JavaScript.
Any leads?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Understand the use of the two timer functions in JavaScript:

- `setTimeout` - Do once after a specified time.
- `setInterval` - Do infinite times every specified time.

Simply replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval`:

```
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('divId');
   setTimeout(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 500);
}
```

Or, if you wanna make it really **blink**, do this, as the above one just flips it once, and you need to do it twice:

```
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('divId');
   setTimeout(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 500);
   setTimeout(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 1000);
}
```

If not twice, use it nested:

```
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('divId');
   setTimeout(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
       setTimeout(function() {
          f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
       }, 500);
   }, 500);
}
```

See the timing functions and seconds for both the functions.

---

**Update**

Looks like the OP wants an Yellow Fade Effect once the page is loaded:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#fade-it").delay(150).animate({
    "background-color": "#fc9"
  }, 350, function () {
    $("#fade-it").animate({
      "background-color": "#fff"
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#fade-it {padding: 15px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade-it">
  Welcome!
</div>
```

> **Note:** I have used jQuery and jQuery UI for this, we can also perform in pure CSS.

---

**Update:** Using pure CSS animation.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#fade-it {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
#fade-it {
  -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="fade-it">
  Welcome!
</div>
```

Comment: I want to just highlight it and make the div stay there. My div vanishes !

Comment: This is the correct answer. I could also mention that if you want to use setInterval another time, you should set it to a variable, e.g. `var myInterval = setInterval(function() {....` This will allow you to stop the interval whenever you want to by executing `clearInterval(myInterval)`. You can also stop a timeout before it has been executed by doing the same thing as the interval and executing `clearTimeout(myTimeout)`

Comment: @sahana Remove the second function then. You need to just show it once after a certain time period or? Lemme ask you. Should it happen like: `show`, `hide`, `show` or `hide`, `show`?

Comment: @Praveen It should be visible but it should highlight once the page is loaded.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen Thanks for the support. I do agree we can use `clearInterval` but it requires unnecessary flags right? Check if it has executed twice and then clear, blah blah!?

Comment: @sahana You want something like an Yellow Fade effect?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I agree, your answer is correct, I was just mentioning the possibility :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not a fade out. Just it should blink once. Highlighting is what I am trying to do for the div.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Possible to do just with Javascript or CSS ?

Comment: @sahana Yes, using `animation` and `keyframes`, but then it will not work on IE 8 and below. Is that fine?

Comment: @sahana A **tip** for you. Since it is done by pure CSS, it is more performant than JavaScript and also smooth. CSS uses your Graphics Driver GPU to perform transitions and animations, rather than CPU to calculate and do.

Comment: @sahana Can you kindly check the updated answer and let me know what you think? `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks a ton. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here the solution.

Please follow the code below. First make CSS for fade in effect and on click function add 'fadeIn' class to that particular 'div'.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
 @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
 @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 0s;
   animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

And add class 'fadeIn' when click event happend.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function flash() {
    $('.highlight').fadeOut(500);
    $('.highlight').fadeIn(500);
}

setTimeout(flash, 1000);
```

```css
.highlight{
 background:#red;
 border:15px solid #000;
 padding:50px;
 margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="highlight">Ganesh Putta</div>
```

Comment: Er... This is not the effect OP is asking. Not even close.

Comment: Not fade effect bro... Check, it's just BG Change. But yes, better than before.